# Регистрация неудачных попыток входа

Tags: windows, безопасность, администрирование

Есть ли какие-нибудь программы, которые сохраняют в файл на рабочем столе все неудачные попытки входа в систему с временной меткой с точность до секунды?

Это необходимо для обнаружения попыток посидеть за моим компьютером во время моего отсутствия.

Answer (score 7):

По идее, такое делается при помощи [встроенного в систему аудита](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc787567(v=ws.10).aspx).

Запустите редактор политик (<kbd>Win + R</kbd>, `gpedit.msc`), зайдите в раздел `Конфигурация компьютера\Конфигурация Windows\Параметры безопасности\Локальные политики\Политика аудита\`. Выберите `Аудит событий входа в систему`.

[image: Аудит]

Двойной клик по этому пункту открывает окошко, в котором вы можете включить/выключить логирование успешных и неуспешных попыток логина:

[image: окошка настройки]

То же повторите для пункта `Аудит входа в систему` (это не одно и то же).

Для просмотра лога попыток входа запустите Просмотр событий (<kbd>Win + R</kbd>, `eventvwr.msc`) и найдите там ваше событие в `Журналы Windows\Безопасность\`. Например, событие входа пользователя в систему имеет код 4648, выхода — 4647.

Comment: это все конечно хорошо, но я хотел иначе об этом узнавать...)))

Comment: @May_be: Отредактировал ответ, поменял «Аудит входа в систему» на «Аудит событий входа в систему».

Comment: @May_be: Это — готовое, встроенное в систему средство. Всё остальное непонятно, как правильно встраивать. Если хотите, вы можете написать более удобный просмотрщик ивентов :)

Answer (score 5):

**Плюс к ответу @VladD:**

В версиях Windows не поддерживающих работу в домене (ниже уровня Professional), оснастка управления `gpedit.exe` и групповые политики недоступны. Для версии Win7 и выше (более старых под руками нет, придется проверить самостоятельно если нужно), вместо `gpedit.exe` используются шаблоны безопасности. Добраться до них можно следующим образом: запускаем `mmc.exe` -> Файл -> Добавить оснастку -> **Шаблоны безопасности** -> добавить -> Ok. Создаем новый шаблон и настраиваем аудит, как в ответе у @VladD.

**UPD**
Забыл написать о том как применить созданный шаблон. Исправляюсь.

Для этого понадобится оснастка **Анализ и настройка безопасности**. Добавляется в консоль аналогично предыдущей. Работа с данной оснасткой подробно описана **[тут](http://www.oszone.net/11640/security_analysis)**.
А если кратко:
1. **Создать или открыть базу данных** политик безопасности. При создании новой базы нужно указать файл шаблона созданный ранее.
2. **Анализ компьютера...** - сравниваем настройки шаблона с текущими активными и вносим необходимые правки.
3. **Настройка компьютера...** - применяем измененные настройки.

Для незнакомых с MMC - действия с данной оснасткой производятся с помощью контекстного меню по правому клику на названии оснастки в дереве консоли слева.

Кроме того что системный аудит нормально работает "из коробки", можно настроить триггеры в системном планировщике задач на срабатывание по определенным событиям любого системного лога, включая лог аудита. И вот тут уже можно прописать запуск своей программы, которая должна реагировать на событие.

На правах рекламы: изучите возможности MMC и доступных в вашей версии Windows оснасток. Это сильно упростит управление настройками Windows без необходимости лазить руками в реестр и молиться, что автор рецепта ни где ни чего не напутал, вы все правильно прописали и система не превратится в тыкву после перезагрузки. Хотя шанс последнего остается всегда, поэтому наиболее мощные средства управления, такие как групповые политики, недоступны в домашних версиях.