# Невозможно управлять службой на компьютере

Tags: c#, service, служба

Написал службу. Она работает так как нужно. Решил сделать к ней интерфейс. Единственый способ взаимодействия со службой нашел через класс `ServiceController`. Соответственно пытаюсь с помощью метода `ServiceController.ExecuteCommand()` передать команду службе, но в ответ получаю ошибку: "Невозможно управлять службой "службанейм" на компьютере". Интерфейс запущен с правами администратора. Как пофиксить эту ошибку?

Comment: Прав администратора может быть недостаточно. Нужно право управлять конкретной службой. Я [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/709316/198316) 
 уже писал как задать права пользователю или группе на управление службой.

Comment: @rdorn, тогда немного не понятно следующее: я вполне могу из интрефейса (без назначения особых прав) останавливать и запускать службу, проблема возникает, когда я пытаюсь оправить службе просто цифровую команду. Т.е. где-то у меня прав хватает, а где-то нет?

Comment: именно. В том ответе в [справке к Subinacl](https://rdpdog.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/subinacl-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0/) целый список отдельных прав для служб, ну и, разумеется, там есть полный доступ, но он по умолчанию, вроде, только у системы, точно не помню уже.

Comment: @rdorn, попробовал использовать Subinacl, предоставил себе полный доступ (F) к данной службе, но по-прежнему получаю ту же ошибку. В чем пожет быть еще загвоздка?

Comment: Возможно проблемы в вызываемом методе

Comment: @rdorn, по сути, метод описан в вопросе. Ничего больше. В качестве параметра передается число типа int32. Проще уже некуда.

Comment: Я имел ввиду метод в службе. Она точно умеет принимать команды? Просто если вы, например, описали у службы методы старт и стоп, то будет работать только старт и стоп, а рестарт - нет, несмотря на то, что это по сути последовательность стоп-старт

Comment: перегруженный метод OnCustomCommand() в ней тоже есть. По идее этого должно быть достаточно

Comment: Зацепите к запущенной службе отладчик и "послушайте" что происходит при вызове метода. Может там эксепшн какой валится

Comment: @rdorn, все похоже на то, что метод даже не пытается стучать в службу и валится еще до этого.

Comment: @rdorn,и не похоже, а точно не забегает.

Comment: Проблему решил. Все было до крайности просто. Значение команды должно быть в пределах от 128 до 256. Все работает.

Comment: Тогда стоит описать подробности решения в ответе. Я считаю. что это полезная информация. Если найдете ссылки на документацию, где это описано тоже стоит добавить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение своей проблемы я нашел. Однако, я думаю, что стоит в целом описать комплекс действий, которые необходимо предпринять для передачи своих команд службе Windows.

1. Дать пользователю права как минимум на запись в службу. (Я дал полный доступ, поскольку приложение мое доступно только администраторам системы) Делал я это с помощью утилиты Subinacl. Параметры для запуска выглядят примерно так: `/service "имя_службы" /grant="имя_пользователя_Windows"=F`
2. При использовании метода `ServiceController.ExecuteCommand()` внимательно изучить [документацию по методу](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.executecommand?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ServiceProcess_ServiceController_ExecuteCommand_System_Int32_). В моем случае **не было учтено ограничение по допустимым значениям команд** из-за чего я и потратил кучу времени.
3. Обязательно добавить в службу (при наличии исходников) метод обработки команд `protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)`.